# Using strtok in C to convert a date string to ints

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, strtok

I'm having trouble using the `strtok()` function. I feed this a date of `01/01/2000`; my
expected output is: 1, 1, 2000; however I'm just getting 1, 1, 1.
Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "date.h"
#include <string.h>

struct date{
int day;
int month;
int year;
};

Date *date_create(char *datestr){

printf("inside date_create");
char delim[] = "/";
Date* pointerToDateStructure = malloc(sizeof(Date));
 printf("%s",datestr);
char string[10];
*strcpy(string, datestr);
pointerToDateStructure->day = atoi(strtok( string, delim));
pointerToDateStructure->month = atoi(strtok( string, delim));
pointerToDateStructure->year = atoi(strtok( string, delim));
printf("%d", pointerToDateStructure->day);
printf("%d", pointerToDateStructure->month);
printf("%d", pointerToDateStructure->year);

return pointerToDateStructure;
}
```

Comment: have you tried feeding it the data 1/2/3 ?

Comment: ccpp.c:15:1: error: unknown type name ‘Date’. It seems you are confusing C and c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you want to **use `strtol` instead of `atoi`** (or `sscanf`, see below). The function `atoi` is unsafe.

Second, `strtok` needs `NULL` instead of `string`:

```
pointerToDateStructure->day = atoi(strtok( string, delim));
pointerToDateStructure->month = atoi(strtok( NULL, delim)); /* NULL instead of string. */
pointerToDateStructure->year = atoi(strtok( NULL, delim)); /* See above. */
```

Third, you are not checking the value returned by `strtok`.

As a side note, are you sure `sscanf` can't parse your data ?

```
sscanf(str, "%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year)
```

**EDIT** Explanation by [abelenky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky):

*The function strtok has state. It "remembers" what string it was working on before, and if you pass "NULL", it continues to work on that same string, picking up where it stopped before. If you pass it a string parameter each time, it starts at the beginning each time.*

Comment: +1 on the `sscanf` side note. strtok is unsafe just as atoi is unsafe. (not that I don't still use both, but if you're having problems, use sscanf and strtol).

Comment: @abelenky Excellent explanation I've included it in the answer.

Comment: Note too that `strtok()` demolishes its input string, writing NUL `'\0'` bytes over the delimiters as it encounters them, and without telling you which delimiter it found.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf(str, "%02d/%02d/%[^\n], &day, &month, &year)` is the one of the easiest options, but you should be precise with the format; otherwise everything will go wrong.

If you really want to use `strtok()`, use it in the exact way as cnicutar said but be precise with verification at each step.

Comment: Why did you use a string for the year instead of another integer (because the `%[^\n]` format is for character data)?

Comment: if u use %[^\n], it takes upto NULL value.

Comment: Yes, but it expects to put the result into a character string, not an integer.